# How to modify forloop function to work with SQL queries instead of pre defined values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL which displays the following data:

```
LOCATION                  LINK                 TAGS
New Rochelle              nr.htm               5
Purchase                  pr.htm               3
Rye                       ry.htm               8
Scarsdale                 sc.htm               2
White Plains              wp.htm               9
Yonkers                   qw.htm               5
```

I have the following `<asp:Repeater>` set up in my page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="menu_ul_1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="my-menu ulLocation" id="ulLocation_selector">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="large btn" href='<%# Eval("href_li")%>'>
                        <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
                        <span class="name"><%# Eval("DisplayText")%></span>
                        <span class="count"><%# Eval("DisplayQty")%></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

The following C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /****************** THE BELOW IS GENERATING UL > LI ******************/

        DataTable newsDataTable = new DataTable();

        // add some columns to our datatable
        newsDataTable.Columns.Add("href_li");
        newsDataTable.Columns.Add("DisplayText");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            DataRow newsDataRow = newsDataTable.NewRow();
            newsDataRow["href_li"] = "?sc=item_" + i;
            newsDataRow["DisplayText"] = "List Item # "+i;
            newsDataTable.Rows.Add(newsDataRow);
        }
        menu_ul_1.DataSource = newsDataTable;
        menu_ul_1.DataBind();
    }
```

How can I modify the above code so instead of using the inner for loop, I can use the number of rows in my SQL table and fill in the following value:

```
'<%# Eval("href_li")%>' = LOCATION
'<%# Eval("DisplayText")%>' = LINK
'<%# Eval("DisplayQty")%>' = TAGS
```

Comment: Why can't you just bind menu_ul_1.DataSource = dsLocation?

Comment: @RickS Because the evaluated properties in the markup don't match the query's fields.

Comment: So change the markup.

Comment: @RickS He's also adding in some literal strings, and using the row's index; it's not a direct mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OleDbDataReader` would be an appropriate way to load database information into an `asp:Repeater`.  The reader can be bound directly to the repeater as the data source.

```
string connectionString = "< your connection string >";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT LOCATION, LINK, TAGS FROM [dbo].[NewsTable]";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        menu_ul_1.DataSource = reader;
        menu_ul_1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

In your `ItemTemplate`, the column names from the query should be supplied to the `Eval` expressions.

```
<a class="large btn" href='<%# Eval("LINK")%>'>
    <span class="check"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></span>
    <span class="name"><%# Eval("LOCATION")%></span>
    <span class="count"><%# Eval("TAGS")%></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... Wouldn't I need a foreach statement to loop through the rows in the table?

Comment: No, that's the beauty of data binding.  It will iterate all the rows returned by the reader automatically.

Comment: @SiKni8  This is what i was commenting on for you to do.

Comment: @RickS Yes, but dsLocation does not actually contain the data that OP intended to bind.  @SiKni8, you can improve this question by removing the `dsLocation` logic from your example.  It was not actually relevant your requirements.

Comment: My connection string looks like this: `string connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=svrours;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=FALSE;user=zh;pwd=zha;";` I get the following error: `Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).`

Comment: At this point, the customary guidance is that you should create a new question.  But I'm confident that you can determine the correct connection string for your environment.

Comment: Ahhhh yes... Thank you :) Absolutely right... sorry! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JoelAllison I was recommended to use SQL Server Connection... I am not sure if that would be possible with your code :/

Comment: In the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, there are direct analogs `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` that work precisely the same.  Use these and you will be fine.

Comment: @JoelAllison I modified my connection string and everything is working as it should. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just asking how to loop through your data rows?  Something like this:

```
foreach DataRow lobjDataRow in dsLocation.Tables[0].Rows
{
    DataRow newsDataRow = newsDataTable.NewRow();
    newsDataRow["href_li"] = lobjDataRow["Location"] ;
    newsDataRow["DisplayText"] = lobjDataRow["Link"] ;
    newsDataTable.Rows.Add(newsDataRow);
}
```